# Entity Framework 5 Memory Leak

Tags: entity-framework

The application is a Windows Service that is retrieving a Generic List of my entity and then based on the data returned, I am running other tasks. This data is read-only.  There will be no requirement to update the data in the backend store (Oracle 11g).

Why do I believe I have a memory leak?
Despite disposing the context via a using statement, it doesn't seem the GC is harvesting these objects.  While profiling the application, I have noticed that the Heap memory gradually increases throughout the lifetime of the application.  I also notice more than a few GEN 2 Collections, which of course means objects are existing for quite some time before being collected.
This doesn't occur when I just return a manually generated collection of objects.  In that case I see very few GEN 2 collections (good) and the Heap memory doesn't increase gradually.

I am running Entity Framework 5.0/C# 4.5. I am accessing an Oracle database.  I am using the database first approach.

Besides disposing the context immediately, what else can I do to ensure that the GC will collect the context?

```
public IEnumerable<EventServer> GetRegionalEventServers()
    {
        IEnumerable<EventServer> eventServers = null;
        using (AssetEntities context = new AssetEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                eventServers = from p in context.EVENTSERVERS
                               select new EventServer
                               {
                                   ServerName = p.SERVER_NAME,
                                   Domain = p.DOMAIN,
                                   ServerLocation = p.SERVER_LOCATION
                               };

                return eventServers;
            }
            finally
            {
                eventServers = null;
            }
        }                                           
    }
```

Comment: Are there any dynamic proxies, materialized by these contexts, that have a long lifespan?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I am using a dao class to instantiate the context, run the query, and return a generic list of objects to the client.

Comment: These data could well be dynamic proxies. Try what happens if you set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false on the context. (Unless you rely on lazy loading).

Comment: But I am iterating this collection within the service after it's returned from the dao.  Could this be prolonging the lifetime of the context in some manner?  But then I would have to kill the context there on the client to actually get rid of it? It would seem that the client shouldn't know about the context, that would break encapsulation.

Comment: Another observation...If I turn off connection pooling in the connection string, the memory leak is decreased.I was only incrementing the pool by 1 with a max pool of 1.  But when I turn off pooling I get some inconsistent behavior.